# ¿Tengo un problema con un test con assertViewHas en Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, pruebas-unitarias, testing

Buenas noches a todos comunidad, espero se encuentren bien.
Estoy implementando un test en Laravel para lograr acertar que una vista efectivamente contiene los datos, con lo cual estoy utilizando la función **assertViewHas()** pero aún no encuentro el error.

Esta es la función del test, lo que hago es crear un registro (podrían ser varios) que es el quiero verificar que está en la vista, todas las afirmaciones aciertan menos assertViewHas.

[image]

A continuación adjunto el controlador de esa vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al ejecutar los test me salta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco por su tiempo y muchas gracias por leer.